# run in on statement trigger

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Progress 9, Windows.

Two Button Screen.
B1 e B2.
Both give RUN in another program that is on disk.

```
B1                                   B2
--                                   --
RUN p1.w.                            RUN p2.w.
MESSAGE "Back from p1".              MESSAGE "Back from p2".
```

### Correct execution

Click on B1. Open p1 program.
Click on B2. Open p2 program.
Close p2. Show "Back from p2".
Close p1. Show "Back from p1".

### Execution seems wrong

Click on B1. Open p1 program.
Click on B2. Open p2 program.
Close p1. Do not show "Back from p1". B1 button freezes, no action.
Close p2. Show "Bcak from p2". Button keeps running.

It gives the impression that it places the calls in a "stack" and the last one that enters has to be the first one that comes out.
Any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run those .w's with the PERSISTENT keyword and avoid executing any WAIT-FOR statement in the main block.

Comment: The called programs are screens (CRUD).
Persistent calls require several changes.
Such programs are called in other places as well.

Comment: One world, one wait-for. It seems you are violating that rule by executing multiple input blocking statements in parallel. After running p1.w, you should disable the first (menu) window. And disable starting p2.w that way. Or switch to persistent.

Comment: The main program, which has both buttons, is the equivalent of a menu program.
I can open several screens in parallel, however, I am forced to close them in stack format. Therefore, the last screen to open should be the first one to be closed.
Is this really the expected operation?

Comment: With multiple WAIT-FOR's or other input blocking s the statements and no persistence: yes

Comment: OK. 
Thanks for the attention Mike.